# The value of List<String> becomes null when leaving for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing the following function to fetch data from *Excel* using *Apache poi*

```
public static List<List<String>> getXMLData(String RowName,String SheetName ) throws Exception{                   
    List<List<String>> dataToWrite = new  ArrayList<List<String>>();
    try{    
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
        int itotalRow=ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println("itotalRow:"+itotalRow);
        int itotalCol=ExcelWSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println("itotalCol:"+itotalCol);
        List<String> xmlTags = new  ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> xmlvalues = new  ArrayList<String>();

        for(int j=1;j<=itotalCol;j++){
            if(ExcelWSheet.getRow(1).getCell(j).getStringCellValue().isEmpty()==false){
                xmlTags.add(ExcelWSheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue()) ;
                System.out.println("xmlTags:"+j+xmlTags);
            }
            if(ExcelWSheet.getRow(1).getCell(j).getStringCellValue().isEmpty()==false){
                xmlvalues.add(ExcelWSheet.getRow(1).getCell(j).getStringCellValue()) ;
                System.out.println("xmlvalues:"+xmlvalues);
            }
        }
        for(String tag:xmlTags){
            System.out.println("xmlTags:"+tag);
        }

        for(String tagval:xmlvalues){
            //System.out.println("xmlvalues:"+tagval);
        }

        dataToWrite.add(xmlTags);
        dataToWrite.add(xmlvalues);
        for(List<String> tagall:dataToWrite){
            System.out.println("dataToWrite:"+tagall);
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataToWrite;
}
```

Here all the values are assigned to the `List` properly from the Excel sheet.

If I print the `List`'s `xmlTags` & `xmlvalues` inside the for loop all values are printed properly after adding to the `List`.

But, once the for loop exits a null pointer exception is thrown. Here the `List` is reinitiated to `null` and I can't identify why it is happening.

The result of printing inside the for loop is as follows:

```
xmlTags:8[NoResponseOK]  
xmlTags:9[NoResponseOK, TestIndicator]  
xmlTags:10[NoResponseOK, TestIndicator, PrimaryObjectType]  
xmlTags:11[NoResponseOK, TestIndicator, PrimaryObjectType, ChangeSubType]  
xmlTags:12[NoResponseOK, TestIndicator, PrimaryObjectType, ChangeSubType, ChangeTC]  
xmlTags:13[NoResponseOK, TestIndicator, PrimaryObjectType, ChangeSubType, ChangeTC, TranContentCode]  
xmlTags:14[NoResponseOK, TestIndicator, PrimaryObjectType, ChangeSubType, ChangeTC, TranContentCode, ChangeSubType]  
xmlTags:15[NoResponseOK, TestIndicator, PrimaryObjectType, ChangeSubType, ChangeTC, TranContentCode, ChangeSubType, ChangeTC]  
xmlTags:16[NoResponseOK, TestIndicator, PrimaryObjectType, ChangeSubType, ChangeTC, TranContentCode, ChangeSubType, ChangeTC, TranContentCode]
```

Comment: Try to reproduce a small, self contained correct example.

Comment: and spend a minute or two actually formatting your code

Comment: If that's the way how you indent your code, I'm not surprised debugging takes six hours or more.

Comment: Post (add to your question by using [edit]) your exception with full stack trace.

Comment: at least tell us, on which line has NPE occured ?

Comment: The code where you test the content of a cell in row 1 then add the content of a cell in row 0 looks wrong to me.

Comment: I think a stack trace is required - it's unclear to me that it's the `List` and not something else that's null. How do you know it's the `List`? And how do you know you've exited the loop? My money's on you accessing a null `Cell` and trying to call `getStringCellValue()` on it, or something like that.

Comment: The Strack trace just prints the following :java.lang.nullpointerException